# django views - unresolved import

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

I have installed the `cloudinary` image CDN service with `easy_install` and put `cloudinary` into my settings.py as app, did `syncdb --migrate`. To this point everything is fine.

But once I want to use it in views.py:

```
import cloudinary
```

...it is showing the error, `unresolved import: cloudinary`

What can be the reason for this? I thought `easy_install` solves all path related issues while installing. Does it not?

Comment: Your interpreter is probably different from the one that your process is using, it's probably wrapped in a virtualenv.

Comment: What does this means? "put cloudinary into my settings.py". Installed apps?

Comment: @Hedde, what to do then?

Comment: @PauloBu, i registered `cloudinary` in APPS in settings.py.

Comment: type `which python` on bash (assuming you're not on a windows server) to see which one you are using by default then compare it to the one your process is using.

Comment: @Hedde, i am using python26. normally easy_install doesnot set the dependencies?

Comment: @Hedde just a question? If the `INSTALLED_APPS` dig it? It should be available isn't it? Else `settings.py` would've complaint when `syncdb`.

Comment: PyDev is causing it may be? need to restart the Aptana may be?

Comment: Try to `import cloudinary` in a normal `python` shell

Comment: @PauloBu, yeah, it is working in the shell

Comment: Do you get `unresolved import: cloudinary` as an exception or just in the IDE (PyDev)??

Comment: now it is working. i removed the interpreter und added again. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For those who may encounter this issue, the solution that worked for me is:

go to Preferences / PyDev / Interpreter - Python
and remove the Interpreter and do autoconfig again. then it will find the modules and import them